# Mailto link in mail body

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook

I have an requirement in vb.net like, Body of Outlook mail item should contain a link. On clicking that link, another mail item should open with To list and CC list. I am using below code,

```
 string Body = "";
 Body += "Please, click the below link to view the details. %0D%0D"
 Body += "<a href=mailto:" + cc + "?Subject=" + Subject + "> Click here to Approve </a>"
 sMsg = User.Redirect("mailto:" + cc + "?Subject=" + Subject + "&body=" + Body)
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "showalert", sMsg, True)
```

But I am not getting the link properly in Outlook. It is displaying as below,

```
Please, click the below link to view the details. 
<a href=mailto:xxx@domain.com?Subject=DCW Trucking Ltd.> Click here to Approve </a>
```

I need to have only 'Click here to approve as link'.

I should not use Outlook dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you should enclose address into double quotes:

```
Body += "<a href=\"mailto:" + cc + "?Subject=" + Subject + "\"> Click here to Approve </a>"
```

Because currently it's invalid HTML-tag.

Second - you should use this `Body` variable as HTML-body of Mail message, not as text body.

Since it's legacy ASP.NET redirect to mailto address, characters in "body" parameter of this address should be Url-encoded(use HttpUtility.UrlEncode method), so resulting redirect-link should look like this:

```
mailto:test@example.com?subject=Meow&body=Please%2C%20click%20the%20below%20link%20to%20view%20the%20details.%0A%3Ca%20href%3D%22mailto%3Atest%40example.com%3Fsubject%3DMeow%22%3EClick%20here%20to%20Approve%3C%2Fa%3E
```

Comment: The code in my question opens outlook Mail item once the control passes ScriptManager.RegisterStartupscript(...). I need to use the same syntax. I have not supposed to use Outlook dll or MailMessage, SMTP etcc... Is that possible.

Comment: Sorry. It did not work. I am getting Mail with body in the format. '<a+href=xxx@domain.com?Subject=Hi>+Click+here+to+Approve+</a> '. I have used the code  'string Body =  HttpUtility.UrlEncode("<a href=mailto:" + ToMail + "?Subject=" + Subject + "> Click here to Approve </a>");' I need only 'Click Here to approve' to display as link. on clicking that link another mail item should open with To list..

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "I should not use Outlook dll"? Are you not using the Outlook Object Model?

In OOM, set the `MailItem.HTMLBody` property to a properly formatted HTML string that may include links.

Comment: No. Code which I posted above does not contain outlook object. Body is the string. I am passing body string to mailto.

Comment: mailto url only allows plain text body. You cannot pass HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a single button to create a body from a local email program, and import  multiple lines from different textboxes, I came up with:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:sendtoEmailaddress@gmail.com?subject=My Subject Line here&body=" + ((textBox1.Text + "%0A" + textBox2.Text + "%0A" + textBox3.Text)));
```